# SQL Server identity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing a asp.net application and i am using SQL Server 2008. I took a IDENTITY column as `Record_ID` for detail table where i will have trillions of records per year. So just want to ask whats the largest number record id (identity) column can hold and in ASP.NET which data type i should use to handle record id as i am using this id as a reference to update the table data. I don't want to end up being trapped some day.

Guide me accordingly please.

Comment: `bigint`. Up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` if you start the seeding at 0. Potentially double that if you don't. trillions of records per year! really? 1 US trillion would still mean you are doing 31709 inserts per second.

Comment: That's a whopping total of over **9 quintillion** - that's more than **9 billion billions** or **9 milion trillions** - that's a lot of entries! Even with trillions of rows per year, that'll be good enough for **a million years** - will that suffice for you?? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IDENTITY can be any of the integer types, so the size is determined by the actual column type (INT, BIGINT, etc) and not the fact alone that it's an identity.

Max/min values are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

In all cases these are signed values, so (for example) INT is Int32 (or int), and BIGINT is Int64.

Comment: Martin sorry its not trillion its billion i made a boo boo :) but in asp.net which data type i should use to read the BIG INT value?

Comment: @user - It's Joe you should thank but I'm happy to take his credit!

Comment: well I am already trying to accept joe's s answer but cant do it as there is a 6 minutes limitation :)